# Mysqli Class, printing results

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying to expand my PHP abilities past the beginner level. OOP is an end goal. Right now I'm trying to use and understand a class that I can call up to pull information from my database or insert into the database. I found the following tutorial on such a subject, maybe I'm missing something but I can't figure out how to actually print any of the results on screen?

Below is the code provided from the tutorial....

```
    class Db {
    // The database connection
    protected static $connection;

    /**
     * Connect to the database
     *
     * @return bool false on failure / mysqli MySQLi object instance on success
     */
    public function connect() {    
        // Try and connect to the database
        if(!isset(self::$connection)) {
            // Load configuration as an array. Use the actual location of your configuration file
            $config = parse_ini_file('./config.ini');
            self::$connection = new mysqli('localhost',$config['username'],$config['password'],$config['dbname']);
        }

        // If connection was not successful, handle the error
        if(self::$connection === false) {
            // Handle error - notify administrator, log to a file, show an error screen, etc.
            return false;
        }
        return self::$connection;
    }

    /**
     * Query the database
     *
     * @param $query The query string
     * @return mixed The result of the mysqli::query() function
     */
    public function query($query) {
        // Connect to the database
        $connection = $this -> connect();

        // Query the database
        $result = $connection -> query($query);

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Fetch rows from the database (SELECT query)
     *
     * @param $query The query string
     * @return bool False on failure / array Database rows on success
     */
    public function select($query) {
        $rows = array();
        $result = $this -> query($query);
        if($result === false) {
            return false;
        }
        while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
        return $rows;
    }

    /**
     * Fetch the last error from the database
     *
     * @return string Database error message
     */
    public function error() {
        $connection = $this -> connect();
        return $connection -> error;
    }

    /**
     * Quote and escape value for use in a database query
     *
     * @param string $value The value to be quoted and escaped
     * @return string The quoted and escaped string
     */
    public function quote($value) {
        $connection = $this -> connect();
        return "'" . $connection -> real_escape_string($value) . "'";
    }
}
```

And this is how I'm attempting to call it from another files.

```
$db = new Db();
$rows = $db -> select("SELECT `id` FROM `inventory`");
```

I've managed to get output from the database by inserting my echo directly into the the function but that doesn't help my model.

I'm assuming it's stuck in the while loop.
I should probably note that it's been a few years since I've started with PHP and a few years since I've worked with it... Life got in the way I guess
any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: No one will follow your link. Show **your** code

Comment: Makes perfect sense to me! Edited, Thanks

Comment: Now check every step.  In `select` function - `var_dump($result)` If it's `false` - move to `connect` and make sure connection to your database established.

Comment: I'm not sure if your trying to confirm if the database connection is up, it is. I might be in a bit over my head with this.... I can however get the expected output by putting an echo $row['id'] into the while loop in the select function, however that obviously doesn't help much. I know it's working, the output just isn't getting back to the original script where is was called.

Answer (score 1):

Okay,

Thanks u_mulder for making me go through it. It really did take over 15 hours but I figured it out.

Now, I'm not sure I completely understand why but it was a minor error using    []

```
    public function select($query) {
    $rows = array();
    $result = $this -> query($query);
    if($result === false) {
        return false;
    }
    while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
        $rows = $row;
    }
    return $rows;
}
```

Line 8 should read as follows:

```
 $rows = $row;
```